# How to add project local static or dynamic libraries in CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I am trying to learn OpenGL and would like to set up my build environment with cmake. I will use GLEW (OpenGL Extension Wrangler) and freeglut. However there is one problem... Since I am an absolute beginner to "project management" in C++ and cmake I am having hard time pointing to static libraries. I can understand C++ code but compeletly new to C++ based project build systems.

I am just simply trying to generate a Visual Studio 2015 project. My question is: How can show my static libraries to cmake. My project folder structure:

```
build # Folder where I would like cmake generated files to be generated in this directory.
include
|-- GL
|   |-- freeglut.h
|   |-- freeglut_ext.h
|   |-- freeglut_std.h
|   |-- glut.h
|-- glew
|   |-- eglew.h
|   |-- glew.h
|   |-- glxew.h
|   |-- wglew.h
lib
|-- freeglut.lib
|-- freeglut_static.lib
|-- glew32.lib
|-- glew32s.lib
src
|-- main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` file is as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(sb7application)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_library(LINK_LIBS NAMES freeglut freeglut_static glew32 glew32s PATHS lib)

include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LINK_LIBS} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY})
```

Here, basicly what I want to do is to ask CMake to link static libraries in the `lib` folder. However this cmake script doesn't add the Linker input configuration to my visual studio project settings. For example, if I open the generated visual studio project and go to Properties > Linker of the project and add this `lib` directory to additional library directories and specify the libraries (`.lib`s) in Properties > Linker > Input section, it compiles successfuly. Otherwise, it gives a linkage error saying something like `'__imp_glewInit()' cannot be found`.

Yeah, how can I show this `lib` directory and its contents as my static libraries to be linked? If you can explain like you explain to a child and explain each step in detail, I would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: 1) What does `message(STATUS "freeglut libs: ${LINK_LIBS}")` output? 2) In your `find_library` call, does replacing `lib` by `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"` help?

Comment: @oLen It shows NOTFOUND for LINK_LIBS. Also, replacing lib by ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} didn't help.

Comment: Strange, but at least you know that the problem is in this function call. Next I would try to clear the CMake cache (f.i. delete your build directory), sometimes this helps.

Comment: Ohh sorry. I get only the freeglut.lib's path.